# VBA: Add textbox in PowerPoint and assign it to object variable

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I can add a textbox to a slide in PowrPoint, but if I try to assign it to a variable, I get error 13: Type mismatch. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Test()

Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shpTxtBox As Shape

Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT) 'this works, I'm just not gonna write out the path of the presentation

Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(myPresentation.Slides.Count - 14, 12)

'mySlide.Shapes.AddTextbox Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=5, Top:=10, Width:=900, Height:=60 '<---- works
Set shpTxtBox = mySlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=5, Top:=10, Width:=900, Height:=60) '<-----doesn't work

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Dim shpTxtBox as PowerPoint.Shape`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a type mismatch because of your declaration.

```
Dim shpTxtBox As Shape <- this is an Excel shape, not a Powerpoint one.
```

To fix:

```
Dim shpTxtBox as Powerpoint.Shape
```